# EF 5 Code First Add Column

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have created a database using EF 5 Code First, and I now have a field I want to add to a particular table, which will be an int datatype.  I am wondering that if I simply add

`public int NewField { get; set; }`

to my model and add it as a migration, since the table already has data in it will I need to set the field to a nullable int so that I don't lose the existing data, and then after adding the NewField data add another migration to change it back to a non-nullable int?

Answer (score 0):

Altertatively you can add a migration but then manually modify it so that the column has a default value defined. Applying the migration will add a column and set thus default value for all existing rows.